# Parseval Identity and Fourier Coefficients

Tags: fourier-series, parsevals-identity

I have to calculate Fourier coefficients and write Parseval Identity  of :

$ f(x)$ defined as:

$ f(x)=cos^2(x) $

if $ -\pi/2\le x\le\pi/2$

and

$ f(x)=0$

otherwhise in  $L^2(-\pi, \pi)$, in the base of functions

$e_k(x) ={e^{ikx} \over \sqrt{2\pi}}$.

So,

$ {\Huge } c_k ={1\over \sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} cos^2(x)\ \cdot  e^{-ikx}dx={1\over 2\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{-ikx}\ dx  + {1\over 2\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} cos(2x)\ \cdot  e^{-ikx}dx.$

Complex parts of both integrals are odd, so it remains :

${1\over 2\sqrt{2\pi}}\ {\Large (} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}cos(kx)\ dx  +  \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} cos(2x)\ \cdot  cos(kx)dx{\large {\Large )}}={1\over \sqrt{2\pi}}\ {\Large (} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}cos(kx)\ dx  +  \int_{0}^{\pi/2} cos(2x)\ \cdot  cos(kx)dx{\large {\Large )}}$.

$c_k={1 \over \sqrt{2\pi}}{\huge [}{sin(k{\pi \over2}) \over k}+ {1 \over2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} cos(k+2)x\   {\large {\Large }} + {1 \over2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} cos(k-2)x\   {\large {\Large }}{\huge ]} $

$ c_k={1 \over \sqrt{2\pi}}{\huge (}{sin(k{\pi \over2}) \over k}+ {1 \over2}{sin(k{\pi \over2 }+\pi) \over k+2}+  {1 \over2} {sin(k{\pi \over2 }-\pi) \over k-2}{\huge )} ={1 \over \sqrt{2\pi}}{\huge (}{sin(k{\pi \over2}) \over k}- {1 \over2} {sin(k{\pi \over2 }) \over k+2}-  {1 \over2} {sin(k{\pi \over2 }) \over k-2}{\huge )}  $

ObviouslyI have to calculate $c_0, c_2,  c_{-2}$ separately.

My problem is to adjust $c_k$ to be able to calculate $ \sum_{-\infty }^{\infty} |c_k|^2$. I thought to write

$ sin(k{\pi \over2}) = {e^{ik\pi/2} -e^{-ik\pi/2} \over 2i}$

but I still would have 3 terms . So I should  calculate the module squared of a trinomial s, then take all odd/even terms...I'm not sure I procedeed correctly. Thanks in advance to anyone who will help me.

Comment: You can greatly simplify your calculations by making use of $\cos(x) = \dfrac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$.

Comment: I understand but I still would have 3 terms , yet decomposed in simple fracts. Should I square and analyze all 6 terms of the serie?